# Why does Joining objects together stretch UV mapping for some individual faces?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I've seem to encounter some kind of anomaly in my model. I have created a model of a car, composed out of multiple meshes. After joining the pieces together, i began texturing the model, however, the UV maps of certain parts are stretched (but cleanly unwrapped) and distorted in a certain direction, while some unwrap normally.

I've nailed the problem down to where it seems only the base, or mesh i began with unwraps normally, while the other meshes i joined onto it have bad unwraps. I've tried unwrapping individual faces and get the same result, even after marking seams

Here is an example
[image]

What is causing this?

Comment: Did you forget to make seams for the meshes you joined?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out, Selecting the object and pressing CTRL+A in 'Object Mode' then applying  the scale fixed it.

(credit to @Paul Gonet)